# Sharepoint Foundation 2010, Cannot create database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have got install Sharepoint Foundation 2010 -> Server Farm. When I run Configuration wizard and there I create new database on SQL server, then displeyd error:

"An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException. Additional exception information: The specified instance of SQL Server uses an invalid sort SQL_Czech_CP1250_CS_AS. Select the server instance that performs non-binary comparison, in which not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters."

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL Server is configured to use case sensitive collation (CS). SharePoint requires databases to have case insensitive collation (CI). You need to change settings in SQL Server to make sure new databases are created with case insensitive collation.

"The SQL Server collation must be configured for case-insensitive. The SQL Server database collation must be configured for case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, Kana-sensitive, and width-sensitive. This is to ensure file name uniqueness consistent with the Windows operating system."

[Source](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2008668)

Comment: OK thank you, but I'd rather no try, because it's a risk. I've about 8 databases in company and I don't lost it.

I trying second option, yet: Conncet to configuration database. I set database on SQL with CI. But when a i want connect to this database, so error is Cannot find configuration database. I've got all permisions. Comunication sharepoint server with SQL server is ok, but don't find database on SQL. I was trying firewall to off and it's same problem.

Comment: Collation is actually applied on each database separately, so changing the default on server level doesn't change it on existing databases. You could pre-create the SharePoint databases manually to ensure they're created with correct collation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262869(v=office.14).aspx